# (not all) Data can't reach database

Tags: php, sql, function

I want to send data to my database (group_id, user_id and group_name) but only the first two are getting into the database. When I var_dump `$groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);` it gives me the correct group_name. What am I doing wrong?

When I replace  `'" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Invitation_group_name) . "'` with a random word it is working well..

PHP

```
$groupinvitation = new GroupInvitation();

if (isset($_POST["Accept"])) {
    try {
        $group_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["group_id"]);
        $groupinfo = $group->GetGroupInfoByGroupId($group_id);
        $groupname = $groupinfo['group_name'];

        $requestnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acceptID']);
        $groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);
        $groupinvitation-> AcceptGroupRequest($requestnumber);
        $groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);

        $feedback = "Awesome, You just added a friend!";


    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage();

    }
}
```

DECLARATIONS:

```
class GroupInvitation
    {

    private $m_sGroup_invitation_group_name;


        public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue)
        {
            switch($p_sProperty)
            {

                case "Invitation_group_name":
                $this->m_sGroup_invitation_group_name = $p_vValue;
                break;

            }
        }

        public function __get($p_sProperty)
        {
            switch($p_sProperty)
            {

                case "Invitation_group_name":
                return $this->m_sGroup_invitation_group_name ;
                break;

            }
        }
```

FUNCTION:

```
public function AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id)
        {
                $db = new Db();
                $insert = "INSERT INTO tblgroup_member(


                                group_id,
                                user_id,
                                group_name

                          ) VALUES (

                                '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($group_id) . "',
                                '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($number) . "',
                                '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Invitation_group_name) . "'   



                          )";

                $db->conn->query($insert);


        }
```

Comment: First, I suggest to you to use PDO. It's more secure and easy to use. You can find a full doc here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. I'm looking for a solution to your problem now ;)

Comment: What exactly does `$this->Invitation_group_name` return when you var_dump it in your function?

Comment: It is returning the group_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);
$groupinvitation-> AcceptGroupRequest($requestnumber);
$groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);
```

to

```
$groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);
$groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);
$groupinvitation-> AcceptGroupRequest($requestnumber);
```

You could be setting the property after the insert.

Comment: Of course I had to give the data before executing the function.